# How to make cucumber/selenium run Thin server instead of Webrick

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

where do I have to setup or configure to fire cucumber/selenium test to run Thin server instead of the default Webrick server?

Comment: just include the gem 'thin' in your gem file. 
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585544/how-to-run-cucumber-selenium-using-thin-server-instead-of-default-webrick

Answer (score 22):

To explicitly setup Thin, create a file within the features/support directory with the following:

```
Capybara.server do |app, port|
  require 'rack/handler/thin'
  Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => port)
end
```

Comment: fyi, for about a year thin has not been the default

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/5b164d4f1c256f24b6c42475ea15466fcd3f012b