# How to run cucumber selenium using Thin server instead of default Webrick?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

my cucumber features with selenium  runs (for Rails 3 app) using the default Webrick server.

How can I force or setup to run with Thin server instead of Webrick?
Any settings to put in env.rb file or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1) turn off capybara's built in server and run it yourself.

2) Looks like someone patched in the capability here https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/175

Comment: just including the thin server gem `gem "thin"` in Gemfile also did.

Answer (score 6):

This is the new way to do this with recent capybara

```
require "rack/handler/unicorn"
Capybara.register_server(:unicorn) do |app, port, host|
  Rack::Handler::Unicorn.run(app, :Port => port)
end
Capybara.server = :unicorn
```

Comment: Works a treat. After registering as above, I also had to set the server; `Capybara.server = :unicorn`.

Comment: I also had to add `rack-handlers` to my Gemfile, and do `require "rack/handler/unicorn"` before the code in this answer, or I would get "uninitialized constant Rack::Handler::Unicorn (NameError)". I'm on Rack 2.0.5.